# jQuery : displaying a div according to which image i clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm having a trouble to display text according to images i clicked on.

```
<ul id="boutique1">
      <li><a href="#first"><img src="images/image1.jpg">nothing</a></li>
    </ul>
```

When i click on these first link, i want to display that :

```
 <p id="first" style="display:none;">Hello World</p>
```

Into this div :

```
<div id="alert"></div>
```

Now, i have this jQuery function :

```
$('#boutique1 a').live('click',function(){ 

 $('#alert').html(  $($(this).attr('href')) ).slideDown(); 
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#alert').slideUp() },5000) 

 });
```

I don't know why it's not working.

**I only got the #alert div who is showing up empty**

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('#boutique1_item3 a').live('click',function(){ 
  $('#alert').html( $(this.hash).html()).slideDown()
             .delay(5000).slideUp();
});
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/AhnGD/), they key is that [`.html(value)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) takes a string, so you need to call [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to *get* the value on the element you're grabbing content from.

Comment: @Tristan - It's a quick way to get the `#something` out of the `href` property :) It's a DOM property, not a jQuery one.